# selectionIndicatorImage

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

How can I remove this mask?

[image: selectionIndicatorImage]

I don't found any solution about it.

Please help me

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
UIImage* emptyImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"empty.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:emptyImage];
```

selectionIndicatorImage is now empty!

Looks good!

Thanks for all.

Comment: You can use this category to create an empty image: http://ioscodesnippet.com/2011/08/22/creating-a-placeholder-uiimage-dynamically-with-color/